# formatted output using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My problem details:

logs table

userid  offername   amount  uamount offertitle  date

offername are like this

xxx 
yyyy 
zzzz

My query:

```
$sqloffers=mysql_query("SELECT user.username, logs.* FROM logs 
INNER JOIN user ON user.userid = logs.userid  ORDER BY logs.offername DESC ");
```

to display results

```
<?php

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqloffers))  
{

    echo "<tr> ";
    echo "<td>" .$row[username] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row[offername] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .$row[amount] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row[uamount] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .$row[offertitle] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row[date] . "</td>";

     }

     echo "</tr> " ;
?>
```

I want the output to be seperated by each username , aginst offername.

Right now I am getting out like this 
username   offername   amount    date  
user1       xxxx      xxx            xxxx  
user1       xxxx      xxx            xxxx  
user1       xxxx      xxx            xxxx  
user1        yyyy     yyyy           yyyy  
user1        yyyy     yyyy           yyyy  
user1        yyyy     yyyy           yyyy

and so on .

I want the output like this

username   offername   amount    date 
user1       xxxx      xxx            xxxx  
user1        yyyy     yyyy           yyyy  
user1        zzz      zzz              zzzz  
user2       xxxx      xxx            xxxx  
user2        yyyy     yyyy           yyyy  
user2        zzz      zzz              zzzz  
userN       xxxx      xxx            xxxx  
userN        yyyy     yyyy           yyyy  
userN        zzz      zzz              zzzz

Clarification:

this table contains offers from different companies completed by users.
I need out in such a way that , if user 1 completed 10 offers from offername xxx, and 5 from offername yy, then output should display user1 only 1 time against company xx, and display its count for xxx company, and so on.

I hope i have clarified the question.

Solution that worked after accepting answer:

```
$sqloffers=mysql_query("
SELECT user.username, logs.offername, logs.date, SUM(logs.uamount) as uamount, SUM(logs.amount) as amount ,count(*) as counter 
FROM logs
INNER JOIN user 
ON user.userid = logs.userid  
GROUP BY user.username
ORDER BY logs.offername DESC
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.To be more clear with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, just to start:

```
$sqloffers=mysql_query("
SELECT user.username, logs.offername, logs.date, SUM(logs.uamount) as uamount, SUM(logs.amount) as amount ,count(*) as counter 
FROM logs 
INNER JOIN user 
ON user.userid = logs.userid  
GROUP BY user.username, logs.offername, logs.date
ORDER BY logs.offername DESC 
");
```

Comment: does not display any records, empty table appears. only the header are shown.

Comment: so check my names? I have no idea about your real table structure. does `offername` belongs to `logs` table? because my changes do nothing new, there is no filter no WHERE conditions, so that can be only names of fields that break the result

Comment: logs table :::::::
userid offername amount uamount offertitle date 
I only need to pick username from other table rest is same.
I have edited the question again with more codes i am using

Comment: so I can see 6 fields you try to output, but in your data samles you use only 4 and that is strange. so is offername usually empty? what type is set for this column? try to change `offername` in my query to `offertitle`

Comment: after change still same, in my question, i displayed sample data.offertitle is empty some times marked as N/A, but offername is always filled up.

Comment: so just comment my `GROUP BY` for now. does it work?

Comment: that is very weird...:-(

Comment: after commenting group by, it has display offer from one offername, and ignored the second offername.

Comment: $sqloffers=mysql_query("
SELECT user.username, logs.offername, logs.date, SUM(logs.uamount) as uamount, SUM(logs.amount) as amount ,count(*) as counter 
FROM logs
INNER JOIN user 
ON user.userid = logs.userid  
GROUP BY user.username
ORDER BY logs.offername DESC

---------- This has worked, displayed the exact data , as required

Answer (score 0):

```
use DISTINCT Modifiers.
DISTINCT  logs.*
```